# optimize query taking too long to run

Tags: sql, data-analysis, azure-databricks

I am trying to run a SQL query in azure databricks. But this query is taking too long to execute.
Could you please suggest what optimization I can do in this below query to make it more faster

```
SELECT 
LOWER(get_json_object(element_at(params,'ans.client_payload'), '$.ACTIONBLOCK_ID')) AS content_id,
lower(element_at(params,'event.type')) as event_type,
count(distinct(userguid)) as num_usr,
count(*) as num_events

FROM my_table

where event_date >= '2023-04-03'
AND event_code = 'ABC_SERVICE'
AND lower(element_at(params,'event.subcategory')) =  'message'
AND lower(element_at(params,'event.type')) in ('render', 'click')
AND element_at(params,'consumer.name') in ('ABC', 'BCC')
AND element_at(params,'source.name') =  'NNC'
and regexp_like(element_at(params,'exp.campaign_id'), '\b12345\b')
and userguid is not NULL
GROUP BY 
LOWER(get_json_object(element_at(params,'ans.client_payload'), '$.ACTIONBLOCK_ID')),
lower(element_at(params,'event.type'))
```

I am trying to execute this query but this is taking too long to execute. looking for suggestions to optimize this query.

Comment: Please post your execution plan. And also a suggestion to look into db.stackexchange. You may consider providing minimum reproducible example (e.g. sqlfiddle) along with the select query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- try to reduce the amount of data that needs to be scanned (select only the columns that are needed + subqueries to filter data before aggregating it

```
SELECT 
  content_id,
  event_type,
  count(distinct(userguid)) as num_usr,
  count(*) as num_events
FROM (
  SELECT 
    LOWER(get_json_object(element_at(params,'ans.client_payload'), '$.ACTIONBLOCK_ID')) AS content_id,
    lower(element_at(params,'event.type')) as event_type,
    userguid
  FROM my_table
  WHERE 
    event_date >= '2023-04-03'
    AND event_code = 'ABC_SERVICE'
    AND lower(element_at(params,'event.subcategory')) =  'message'
    AND lower(element_at(params,'event.type')) in ('render', 'click')
    AND element_at(params,'consumer.name') in ('ABC', 'BCC')
    AND element_at(params,'source.name') =  'NNC'
    and regexp_like(element_at(params,'exp.campaign_id'), '\b12345\b')
    and userguid is not NULL
)
GROUP BY 
  content_id,
  event_type
```

- make sure that table has appropriate indexes defined

you may want to create an index on `event_date` `event_code` `element_at(params,'event.subcategory')` `element_at(params,'event.type')` `element_at(params,'consumer.name')` `element_at(params,'source.name')` `element_at(params,'exp.campaign_id')` `userguid`

ps. be mindful of the size of the index(you don't want it to be too big)